# How to create new column in Data Frame to sort values for each id based on date column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

- Column my_date is in datetime format.
- In my real DataFrame I have many more columns.

  | id | my_date | col1 |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 111 | 2023-05-15 | 1 |
  | 111 | 2023-05-14 | 11 |
  | 111 | 2023-05-13 | 2 |
  | 222 | 2023-10-11 | 3 |
  | 222 | 2023-10-12 | 55 |

And I need to create new column col_x where for each id will be value 1,2,3 and so on based on date in column my_date. So, for each id in column col_x has to be 1 in the early date from my_date and so on.

So, as a result I need something like below:

| id | my_date | col1 | col_x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2023-05-15 | 1 | 3 |
| 111 | 2023-05-14 | 11 | 2 |
| 111 | 2023-05-13 | 2 | 1 |
| 222 | 2023-10-11 | 3 | 1 |
| 222 | 2023-12-12 | 55 | 2 |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could use a [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['col_x'] = df.groupby('id')['my_date'].rank('dense').astype(int)
```

Which is more or less equivalent to finding the sorting order (e.g. using [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), or `rank('first')`), except it will rank the duplicate values equally:

```
df['col_x'] = df.groupby('id')['my_date'].transform(np.argsort).add(1)
```

Output:

```
    id    my_date  col1  col_x
0  111 2023-05-15     1      3
1  111 2023-05-14    11      2
2  111 2023-05-13     2      1
3  222 2023-10-11     3      1
4  222 2023-10-12    55      2
```

Example with duplicate values:

```
    id    my_date  col1  rank('dense')  argsort+1  rank('first')
0  111 2023-05-15     1              3          4              4
1  111 2023-05-14    11              2          2              2
2  111 2023-05-14     9              2          3              3
3  111 2023-05-13     2              1          1              1
4  222 2023-10-11     3              1          1              1
5  222 2023-10-12    55              2          2              2
```